# Validations in UITextField

Tags: uitextfield, swift4

I have 3 UITextFields(name, email, phoneNumber). I want to put validations which are:

1. Name -> Allowed: (a-z), (A-Z)
2. Email -> Allowed: ensure it ends with something like this "@gmail.com"
3. PhoneNumber -> Allowed: (0-9), and has 10 digits.

Also, for number field, the keypad should be numeric keypad.

Comment: Maybe you should search for `validate UITextField Swift`. You should the be able to write your own code... And the for the keyboard (which should be a different question) try `phoneNumberText.keyboardType = .asciiCapableNumberPad`

Comment: I want help in case of email validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For email validation:-

```
    func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@gmail+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
    }
```

> How to use:-

```
    if isValidEmail(testStr: "john@gmail.com"){
        print("Valid emailID")
    }
    else{
        print("invalide EmailID")
    }
```